# can i get mac address of my router, any way of doing this?

Tags: android, android-studio, wifi

I'm looking for a method for my project to identify the specific wifi network for this I studied that mac address of the router is always same which does not change whereas physical address mac change device by device, so is there any way to get mac address of router or any alternative method to identify specific wifi network.

Comment: I believe MAC address is the physical address of any device.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for [WifiInfo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo)
First you get an instance of the WifiManager:

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Then get the WifiInfo object:

```
wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
```

This can get you the SSID, MAC, Frequency, etc for your current network connection.